# If X And Y Are Coordinates, What Are Rows And Columns?

Tags: javascript, overloading, naming-conventions, naming

I am writing a small tile based game and am having a hard time deciding on the language I should use to best describe a few functions as simply as possible. I want my function names to be expressive of what the function does without making them too long. Here is my issue:

These functions calculate row and column positions in a tile map given a point's x and y coordinates.

```
var tile_width  = 32;
var tile_height = 32;

function getColumnFromX(x) { return Math.floor(x / tile_width); }

function getRowFromY(y) { return Math.floor(y / tile_height); }
```

As you can see, these functions are very expressive. You know that one gets the column position in the map that x lies in and the other gets the row position in the map that y lies in. The problem is that I don't need two functions to do this because `tile_width` and `tile_height` have the same value.

So what I really have is:

```
var tile_size = 32;

function getColumnOrRowFromXOrY(x_or_y) { return Math.floor(x_or_y / tile_size); }
```

That name is too long and cumbersome and other functions like `getColumnOrRowCenterFromColumnOrRow` are unacceptable even though their names describe exactly what is being done.

My unfinished solution is to replace `ColumnOrRow` and `XOrY` with their own descriptive words. `XOrY` can logically be replaced with `Coordinate`, but I don't know what to replace `ColumnOrRow` with.

My question is, what are column and row? If x and y are coordinates, what are columns and rows? I know they are Grid Coordinates, but compound words kind of defeat the purpose of simplifying the name.

Knowing the descriptive word could turn the function name above into:

```
function getWordFromCoordinate(coordinate) { /* ... */ }
```

Where Word is the word that describes what column and row are.

At the heart of this question is wanting to know which single English word can describe row or column in a mathematically accurate way.

Knowing the anatomy of a database Table might be helpful, but I found nothing of much use online. Also, the fact that JavaScript doesn't support function overloading makes naming functions that do the same thing with slightly different parameters a little more tedious.

Comment: You could just go with a very generalised `getProportion => Math.floor(y / tile_height)` that is not going to be too cumbersome but also not very descriptive. You can still have the previous function names by just aliasing them `getColumnFromX = getProportion`. You're still reusing code and naming it appropriate. You really don't want to wander if a call `getColumnOrRowFromXOrY(5)` is for `X` or `Y`.

Comment: The problem arises due to the different functions I have and how similar they are. `getColumnOrRowCenterFromColumnOrRow` and `getColumnOrRowCenterFromXOrY` return the same thing from different inputs. They are both useful, but named poorly. I'm trying to narrow it down to `getWordFromWord` and `getWordFromCoordinate` (where Word can describe column or row). Really this is an English language question. I probably should post it in a technical writers forum, but Stack Overflow is where I always go for answers.

Comment: vectorToPos(x_or_y);

Comment: A horizontal or vertical matrix with one row or column can be called a vector matrix, but I'm not sure if every row and/or every column of a matrix can be considered its own vector. Or can it... I am researching more now.

Comment: I think it can, but I had in mind something like , vectorToPos({x:64,y:32}) returning {col:2,row:1} or if x or y was undefined just returning the corresponding row or column      every position can be defined by a vector with a scalar value e.g n*[1,0]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about naming things, not about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: It is off topic and it's not about programming. I'm just trying to find the word that describes rows and columns in an array or Matrix. In that way it's relative to programming or at least math. Vector is pretty close, but vectors are one dimensional. In a 2D array the vectors can only be in the rows or the columns, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

I found a satisfactory name here: [Grid Track Concept - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-track-concept)

According to the W3C recommendation, "Grid track is a generic term for a grid column or grid row..."

You can read more about Grid Tracks here: [Grid Tracks - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Grid_Tracks)

"Track" logically describes a grid column or row. While the definition isn't used in mathematics, it is used in describing the CSS Grid layout and will work for my purposes. If anyone knows of a better word to classify columns and rows, please feel free to comment.